# How are USB ports related to the computer power, and why would they cause my computer to freeze?

Tags: 10.10, hardware, usb, laptop, freeze

I have an issue with my new Toshiba laptop. Whenever I plug in an external USB device, if the laptop is not plugged in to the wall, the laptop freezes. However, nothing happens if the laptop is plugged in to the wall.

When I say the laptop freezes, I mean it really freezes. The only way to recover is to hard reboot.

My question is, what could be causing this? Could it be the extra power drain from the sub devices that causes this (even the simplest flash drives cause a freeze)?

Please help me out, it's very annoying.

Thanks

## EDIT

Doing a google search, I found that there was a BIOS update that I didnt have. After updating the BIOS, I no longer have this problem.

Laptop model: Toshiba Portege R705-P35

old BIOS: 1.70

new BIOS: 1.80

Thanks.

Comment: One weird thing to check..... Look for your laptop model in Google to see if it usually has (no matter the OS) this problem. My desktop, for instance, freezes (although not always) when connecting USB devices because of.... some grounding problem with the MB and the front panel hub! In my case it's absolutely OS unrelated and the only workaround I've found is to "ground" my devices -and myself- prior to plugging them in. Nothing to lose in trying :).

Comment: Please boot the system and cause the freeze by inserting a USB device. Then reboot and look at the end of the file `/var/log/dmesg.1` - do you see anything suspicious there? You can post here as link to http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @luri your comment is a good answer, perhaps not *THE* answer, but one that would have granted you my vote :-p

Comment: Posted it as an answer, in case it helps some(lazy)one not wanting to read comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One weird thing to check..... Look for your laptop model in Google to see if it usually has (no matter the OS) this problem. My desktop, for instance, freezes (although not always) when connecting USB devices because of.... some grounding problem with the MB and the front panel hub! In my case it's absolutely OS unrelated and the only workaround I've found is to "ground" my devices -and myself- prior to plugging them in. Nothing to lose in trying :).

Comment: Not quite a hardware issue, but your advice brought me to my solution. Thanks

Comment: @BDuelz also consider sharing your solution to help others

Comment: (I saw the author edited the question and posted the answer there)

Comment: I added the solution to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The USB port specification is 5V @ 500mA of course not all usb devices will draw this current but some might (charging mp3 players for one) If your psu is on the weak side it might just be enough to cause the computer to freeze.